# Sum of array numbers in Powershell

Tags: powershell

i am completely new using PowerShell and coding in general.
I want the sum of all the numbers inside my array. after several attempts, I'm not able to get it. Please help!!

This is my code:

```
$Numbers = @(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

function LUFEN($Num_3){
       for($Rept = 0; $Rept -le $Numbers.Length -1; $Rept++){
       if($Num_3 -eq $Numbers[$Rept]){
        return " The number exists."
       }
   }

$Num_3= Read-Host("Type a number")
LUFEN($Num_3)
```

Also, I where can I fix the indentation in the Ps ISE? I cannot find the option.
Thanks!

Nothing has worked for me :(

Comment: `($Numbers | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum`

Comment: As aside, in PowerShell you don't call on a function with a parameter in between brackets (like for instance you would using a .Net method). Use a **space** character instead:  `LUFEN $Num_3`